# How do I use the diagrams library with GTK drawables?

Tags: haskell, gtk, haskell-diagrams

I'm trying to learn how to draw diagrams using the [diagrams library](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/) and the Cairo / GTK backend. I've got a blank window to appear, but my drawing won't render. What am I doing wrong?

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Diagrams.Backend.Cairo
import Diagrams.Backend.Cairo.Gtk
import Diagrams.Prelude

main :: IO ()
main = do
  initGUI
  window <- windowNew
  canvas <- drawingAreaNew
  canvas `on` sizeRequest $ return (Requisition 1000 1000)
  set window [ containerBorderWidth := 10,
               containerChild := canvas ]
  canvas `on` exposeEvent $ renderFigure
  onDestroy window mainQuit
  widgetShowAll window
  mainGUI


renderFigure :: EventM EExpose Bool
renderFigure = do
   win <- eventWindow
   liftIO $ renderToGtk win $ toGtkCoords figure
   -- liftIO $ defaultRender win figure
   return True


figure :: Diagram Cairo R2
figure =  unitCircle # scaleX 0.5 # rotateBy (1/6) # scale 50
```

I've tried using "defaultRender" (as commented out above), but that gives a type error: apparently "win" is not the right type.

I've read the tutorial and user manual for diagram, but it doesn't actually tell you how to use the Cairo backend.

**Update:** I've got the ellipse to render.  The "renderFigure" function now says:

```
renderFigure :: DrawingArea -> EventM EExpose Bool
renderFigure canvas = do
   -- win <- eventWindow
   liftIO $ do
      -- diagramArea <- widgetGetDrawWindow canvas 
      -- renderToGtk diagramArea $ toGtkCoords figure
      defaultRender canvas figure
   return True
```

and the DrawingArea passed in is the "canvas" referenced in the "canvas `on` exposeEvent..." setting.

But I still can't get it to render a fixed size diagram using "renderToGtk".

**Update 2:** Thanks to Joachim Breitner's answer, I've now got the minimal diagram-on-GTK program looking like this, ready for your cut-and-paste pleasure.

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Diagrams.Backend.Cairo
import Diagrams.Backend.Cairo.Gtk
import Diagrams.Prelude

main :: IO ()
main = do
  initGUI
  window <- windowNew
  canvas <- drawingAreaNew
  canvas `on` sizeRequest $ return (Requisition 256 256)
  set window [ containerBorderWidth := 10,
               containerChild := canvas ]
  canvas `on` exposeEvent $ renderFigure
  onDestroy window mainQuit
  widgetShowAll window
  mainGUI


renderFigure :: EventM EExpose Bool
renderFigure = do
   win <- eventWindow
   liftIO $ renderToGtk win $ toGtkCoords figure
   return True


figure :: Diagram Cairo R2
figure =  unitCircle # scaleX 0.5 # rotateBy (1/6) # scale 50 # fc red
```

Comment: What error do you get? Your original code compiles and runs here (though it doesn't draw anything).

Comment: No error; it just didn't draw anything.  Joachim has answered it though.

Comment: Ah, I see that I misread the question, and thought the "type error" sentence was about the non-commented code. Apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial code actually works. But renderToGtk does not scale the image, so it appears rather small, too small to be visible at that line width. But try

```
figure :: Diagram Cairo R2
figure =  unitCircle # scaleX 0.5 # rotateBy (1/6) # scale 50 # fc red
```

and it will work like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can note that in recent versions of diagrams, you should use

```hs
import Diagrams.Backend.Gtk
```

instead of

```hs
import Diagrams.Backend.Cairo.Gtk
```

and

```hs
figure :: Diagram Cairo
```

instead of

```hs
figure :: Diagram Cairo R2
```

The result now looks like :

```hs
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Diagrams.Backend.Cairo
import Diagrams.Backend.Gtk
import Diagrams.Prelude

main :: IO ()
main = do
  initGUI
  window <- windowNew
  canvas <- drawingAreaNew
  canvas `on` sizeRequest $ return (Requisition 256 256)
  Graphics.UI.Gtk.set window [ containerBorderWidth := 10,
               containerChild := canvas ]
  canvas `on` exposeEvent $ renderFigure
  onDestroy window mainQuit
  widgetShowAll window
  mainGUI


renderFigure :: EventM EExpose Bool
renderFigure = do
   win <- eventWindow
   liftIO $ renderToGtk win $ toGtkCoords figure
   return True


figure :: Diagram Cairo
figure =  unitCircle # scaleX 0.5 # rotateBy (1/6) # scale 50 # fc red
```